# How to create a script using jmeter for scenario based

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2

I want to perform performance testing using JMeter, I have the following scenario which i want to record and run
5 min 300 users(Login) -> 20 min 150 users(assessment save) -> 5 min 40 users (Submit assessment) when users login simultaneously 20 min 50 users (Browsing).
Please refer screenshot for reference.
I want to create a script on the basis of the scenario.[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Record all your use cases separately using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder). After recording make sure to **correlate** any dynamic parameters and validate your test by running it with 1-2 users/loops and looking into [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to inspect request and response details.
2. When it comes to distributing virtual users to perform different workload tasks normally different real user groups should be represented by different [Thread Groups](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group). Other options are in using [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller), [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) or [Weighted Switch Controller](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WeightedSwitchController/), the choice depends on your requirements and user use cases implementation. See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) guide for comprehensive information on using above test elements for custom workload distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is really helping me a lot. but how can I perform Browsing scenario as it has to run simultaneously with only first scenario