# Run multiple threads parallel or sequential in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

[image]I want to perform performance testing using JMeter, I have the following scenario which I want to record and run 5 min 300 users(Login) -> 20 min 150 users(assessment save) -> 5 min 40 users (Submit assessment) when users log in simultaneously 20 min 50 users (Browsing). Please refer screenshot for reference. I want to create a script on the basis of the scenario.
In this scenario, first 300 users will land on assessment page out of 300, 20 users will browse then 150 users will complete then 40 users Submit assessment and parallel 10 users download report in 5 min

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a script using jmeter for scenario based](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729112/how-to-create-a-script-using-jmeter-for-scenario-based)

Comment: I have gone through this but I didn't find both Parallel and sequential scenario base